# IBM Worklight - Live published apps on the public AppStore or PlayStore

Tags: app-store, ibm-mobilefirst, google-play

We recently started building a hybrid app with Worklight and targeting AppStore and PlayStore public store submission, not the WL AppCenter. Trying to find Worklight hybrid apps published on the AppStore or GooglePlay markets but there are no clear indicators, also in IBM docs there are no references. I know this is not a really a technical questions, but still we need some details of already published apps.

Are there any public apps available which we can download and install, any examples ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for these iOS apps: myBlue TN, Capital One, UAE - MOI, Dah Sing Bank, BMO Banking, JD Sports, BudgetSanté, Smilez, Ei!, Smart Lotte

Here's a [Case Studies page on IBM Worklight's homepage](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/worklight-foundation).

Comment: Idan, thank you for the prompt answer, found some of them also on the PlayStore.